# analyze program models that induce threads

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, models

Thread is a single stream of control in the flow of a program. Which programming models it induces, and what are possible advantages and disadvantages of such models? (OpenMP, MPI, PThread, Cuda are these the one that induces threads? what are some pros and cons for each program model? )  Thank you

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

You can't both initialize a variable *and* declare it as `extern`. They are two different things.

When you declare a global variable, you can initialize it:

```
// trace_logger.c
int inst_cout= 0;
```

When the global variable may be used by other modules, you name it in a .h file (or define it directly in the other c/cpp source file) that the other modules can include:

```
// trace_logger.h
extern int int_cout;
```

And if you need a global variable but don't want to share it with other modules, you declare it as:

```
// trace_logger.c
static int counter= 0;
```